# Where can i make an html change to a specific page

Tags: pages

One of the pages on my company's website, the hero is displaying incorrectly. It seems that the news page is missing an "h3". Where is the document where i can edit this. an example of the difference is below.

So the careers page has it set up like so:

```
<div class="hero__content">
    <div class="hero__content-wrap  content">                   
        <div class="hero__description" style="opacity: 1;">
            <h3 class="hero__title" style="color: black; font-size: 16px; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
                <div class="hero-page-title">CAREERS</div>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and news is like this:

```
<div class="hero__content">
    <div class="hero__content-wrap  content">                   
        <div class="hero__description" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); opacity: 1;">
            <div class="hero-page-title">NEWS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on the theme you are using. Generally, you can edit the content using WP Visual Editor or HTML Editor.

Comment: If they are coming from your theme, then the answers will help, if they are coming from a plugin, then it depends on that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your theme. To find out exactly which file to edit, add the following code to your `header.php` file inside `/wp-content/themes/nameofyourtheme`:

```
<!-- <?php global $template; print_r($template); ?> -->
```

You can then view the page in question's source and see a comment that tells you the name of the file, which will also be somewhere inside your theme's folder structure.

Once you open that file, it is possible that it's calling another file - WordPress themes sometimes use template parts - if this is the case, the PHP code in the area you're troubleshooting will have a call to `get_template_part` and you'll need to find that separate PHP file. It sounds like this may not be the case though since it differs from page to page.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to install the `What The File` plugin.

I've used it many times to narrow down where a particular template issue is.

Great plugin IMO

Comment: That also has the benefit of not altering files :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more complicated than you're prepared for.

I'm going to guess this is coming from a plugin. The trouble is, even if you identify the exact part of the plugin's code in question, editing the plugin directly would not be advisable, because the next update would break anything you changed.

There's probably a reason the h3 is being shown on one page and not the other. Can you investigate the plugin settings to see why that might be? Is there a checkbox that says "show title" or something like that?

If you really need to find the part of the code, another option is to "grep" for it. This will only work if you have ssh access, or access to a unix command line (like cygwin).

Issue this command in your wp-content folder:

```
grep -R "class=\"hero__title" *
```

If you can share details about the plugins you're using, we might be able to help more. Good luck!